# Can you factor a difference of squares in matrices? Is $A^2 - B^2 = (A+B)(A-B)$?

Tags: matrices, factoring

Can you factorize quadratics like this with matrices?

$$A^2 - B^2 = (A+B)(A-B)$$

I think it's going to be wrong because such a factorization should work even if you switch the order of the terms on the right side, but matrix multiplication isn't commutative.

Comment: Correct.  $A^2-B^2$ is not necessarily equal to $(A+B)(A-B)$.  Note that $(A+B)(A-B)$ can be expanded like usual but keeping order of terms as $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2$.  This would be equal to $A^2-B^2$ if and only if $AB=BA$ which you note is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Cool. Thank you

Comment: Wait, so you could do $$(A+B)^2 = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2 = A^2 + BA + AB + B^2 = (B+A)^2 $$ and $$(A-B)^2 = A^2 - AB - BA + B^2 = A^2 - BA - AB + B^2 = (B-A)^2 $$ both work, no matter what $A$ and $B$ are??

Comment: Yes, both those identities are correct.

Comment: Yes. This is because adding matrices is commutative.

Comment: Yes, and these can be shown as you have here.  Alternatively, and much easier, is to note that addition is commutative so the $A+B$ in $(A+B)^2$ can be written in the other order as $(B+A)^2$.  As for the other, note that scalar multiplication distributes and is commutative, so you have $(A-B)=(-1)(B-A)$ and so $(A-B)(A-B)=(-1)(B-A)(-1)(B-A)=(-1)^2(B-A)^2=(B-A)^2$

Comment: A possible generalization of $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ from scalars to matrices is $A^2-B^2=\left((A+B)(A-B)+(A-B)(A+B)\right)/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
         A^2-B^2 = (A+B)(A-B) \\
       \iff A^2-B^2 = A^2-AB+BA-B^2 \\
       \iff AB=BA
$$
So, this holds iff $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments so far:

You are right as matrix multiplication isn't commutative, as you have said. $(A + B)(A - B) = A^2 - AB + BA - B^2$, so for this to be true, $AB = BA$ which is not necessarily true.

As a counterexample, take:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

where:

$$A^2-B^2= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix} \text{but } (A+B)(A-B) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

However, as matrix addition is commutative, $(A+B)^2 = (B+A)^2$, and likewise $(A-B)^2 = (B-A)^2$. As scalar multiplication distributes and is commutative, $(A-B)(A-B) = (B-A)^2$ by taking out two factors of $-1$.